# Check of moments for pseudo random number generators using CLT

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, central-limit-theorem

I'm trying to get to grips with my lecture notes but cannot understand the idea behind it. I'd really appreciate some help:

"Generate a sequence of size $n$ from stated distribution. Consider an independent sample $X_1,X_2,X_3,..,X_n$ from pdf $f_x(x)$, with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Then the CLT says that... (def. continued - I don't know how to work LaTeX here.) We could then use large sample techniques, for example, in the case of the uniform distribution: $H_0 : \mu = 1/2$ and $\sigma^2 = 1/12$."

At the moment my thinking has led me to think: we have this sample $X_1,...,X_n$ and want the mean and variance to be the same as $\mu = 1/2$ and $\sigma^2 = 1/12$ through hypothesis testing to show uniform distribution - e.g. with the mean you would use the t-distribution for testing? I don't know where the first line comes into the process. Really sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  What is the objective in this setting and what specifically is your question?

Comment: whuber, I'm asking for an explanation for the method and what the purpose of the first line is. My objective is understanding the lecture notes as said above.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial/quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Note that merely matching the mean and variance doesn't demonstrate you have a uniform distribution (it does serve as a way to find bugs, though because if your procedure was wrong in some egregious way they would be highly likely to differ from those values).